# Sketch Engine API search query: How to get frequency?

Tags: python, api, frequency, n-gram, corpus

is anyone familiar with the Python Sketch Engine API and could tell us how to get the frequency of an n-gram?

So far we have this (example from website):

```
import requests
base_url = 'https://api.sketchengine.co.uk/bonito/run.cgi'
data = {
    'corpname': 'bnc2',
    'format': 'json',
    'lemma': 'book',
    'lpos': '-v',
    'username': '...',
    'api_key': '...'
    # get it here: https://the.sketchengine.co.uk/auth/api_access/
}
d = requests.get(base_url + '/wsketch', params=data).json()
print("frequency=", d['freq'])
```

This gives us the frequency of a lemma, but not an n-gram.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint `/wsketch` only takes a single lemma as [input](https://www.sketchengine.eu/user-guide/user-manual/word-sketch/). To work with n-grams a different endpoint should be used, for example `/view`.

```
import requests
base_url = 'https://api.sketchengine.co.uk/bonito/run.cgi'
data = {
    'corpname': 'bnc2',
    'format': 'json',
    'q': 'q[lemma="read"][lemma="book"]',
    'username': '...',
    'api_key': '...'
    # get it here: https://the.sketchengine.co.uk/auth/api_access/
}
d = requests.get(base_url + '/view', params=data).json()
print("frequency=", d['relsize'])
```

Here `'relsize'` refers to [frequency per million](https://www.sketchengine.eu/documentation/frequency-per-million/).